# Get data since a request ajax with asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I would like get all data into an object with request ajax.

This data are get into my controller with a function.
In the headers of my data I have this information:

I have 4 objects allPly create but all data(gramme,lotion and others) equals null or zero.
But the data comment and OtherData it's ok, this works.

Thanks for your help

My Request:

```
var params={};
var allStep21 ={allData..}
$.extend(params,allStep21);
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Request",
    data: params,
});
```

In the headers html:

```
allPly[0][Gramme]:10
allPly[0][Toto]:White
allPly[0][Test]:None
allPly[0][Lotion]:1
allPly[1][Grammage]:11
allPly[1][Toto]:White
allPly[1][Test]:Fine
allPly[1][Lotion]:0
OtherData : 585
Comment: all it's ok
```

In my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Request(AllStep21 allStep21)
{
}
```

In my model:

```
public class AllStep21
{
    public String OtherData { get; set; }
    public String Comment { get; set; }
    public List<allPly> allPly { get; set; }
}
public class allPly
{
    public int Gramme { get; set; }
    public String Toto { get; set; }
    public String Test { get; set; }
    public int Lotion { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you specify the content type is json (contentType: "application/json") and use data: JSON.stringify(params)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a JSON request which allows you to send arbitrary complex objects to your controller actions:

```
var params = { 
    allStep21: { 
        comment: 'some comment', 
        otherData: 'some other data',
        allPly: [
            { toto: 'toto 1', test: 'test 1', lotion: 1, gramme: 1 },
            { toto: 'toto 2', test: 'test 2', lotion: 2, gramme: 2 }
        ]
    } 
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'Request',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    success: function(result) {
        alert('successs');
    }
});
```

The `JSON.stringify` method shown here is natively built into all modern browsers. But if you need to support legacy browsers you need to include the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) script.

Comment: First, thanks for your helps. I have one error, when I put "contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'," and I send my request, I have this error:An item with the same key has already been added...?

Comment: Where do you have this error? What are you doing on the server? I suspect that your problem has nothing to do with the way data is sent in the AJAX request. That should work fine and your `allStep21` action parameter should be populated properly. What you do with this data next is something entirely different.

Comment: When I click on a button, the params is create and request Ajax never send and I have this error.  I put a breakpoint on function into my controller and I never come there...If I remove line contentType, I have no error when I send my request...

Comment: Does your model look exactly as you have shown in your question? If it does, then this should work. Also where do you see this error? In FireBug?

Comment: OK, I see that you have updated your question and the `allPly` model. The `Gramme` property is a simple integer and not an array of integers. That's why it didn't work. I have updated my answer to reflect on this change.

Comment: You have reason(again^^), my models is a little bit different, I have make a test, I copy/past your params and that's work, I have search where is the problem and if I not found, I post here :).  When I use this models all works :p(meaculpa) but my models is a little bit complex ^^ I go search after a solution :)

Comment: If you show your real model I can tell you what's wrong with it. We cannot help you any further if you are not showing your code.

Comment: I found the problem in my code, the model post here is very close of my models.  I wanted a example(simple) of my code but it was a not good idea :s. However, thanks for your code because I resolve my main problem :).  And thanks for yours help :). And I'm sorry for my example :p

Answer (score -1):

What you need is to implement your own model binder. Have a look at these links:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/05/05/iterating-on-an-asp-net-mvc-model-binder.aspx
http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/12/custom-model-binders-in-mvc-3-with-imodelbinder/

I hope it helps.

Comment: -1, he doesn't need to implement any custom binder. It's way too much work for something that's supported out of the box from the framework.